# How does matter equilibrate with radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

For example, there is a thin layer in the Sun, called the photosphere, from which radiation is emitted. It is claimed that radiation is in thermal equilibrium with this layer. How is it possible? Are photons emitted and absorbed there?